# How to deal with device breakpoints in combination with modifiable widths on content?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, media-queries

I'll try to explain this in the best way.

I am developing widgets on a page which can be moved and resized: width and height.

To do this in a nice way, I'm using Bootstrap's grid system which utilizes Flexbox. So for example, I have a list of items.

```
<Container for widget>
  <Row>
    <Column> Col 1 </Column>
    <Column> Col 2 </Column>
...
```

If this was all there was to it, no problem. Flexbox manages the auto-sizes really well.

But some of these Columns need to be bigger than others, and consistently so: since this will be a list, **I want the Columns to be placed similarly on each Row**.

```
<Container for widget>
  <Row>
    <Column size=8 > Very Wide Column 1 </Column>
    <Column> Col 2 </Column>
...
```

Note: Size 8 means 8 out of 12. So far also alright.

But let's say when the width of the widget is Z wide, Very Wide Column 1 needs to take full space.

Now, in Bootstrap there are media breakpoints such as `xs, sm, md, lg, xl`. But these react to the *screen window* and does not react to the *width of the widget*.

In other words, I *could* do this:

```
<Container for widget>
  <Row>
    <Column xs-size=12 md-size=8 > Very Long Column 1 </Column>
    <Column> Col 2 </Column>
...
```

... and so on, but that would not be helpful since the Widget could be very small or very big in the same viewport.

To illustrate this further, have a look on these pictures down below.

XL Media Breakpoint:
[image: XL Media Breakpoint]
Also XL Media Breakpoint:
[image: Also XL Media Breakpoint]

Where the white box is the "widget" (together with the scrollbar)

### Question

How can I *consistently* place the columns in a row based on the width of the container/widget instead of based on the width of the viewport?

### Notes

I think `@container` might have solved the problem if it was more widely supported by browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container

Tech: Boostrap, Flexbox, CSS, SCSS, React

Comment: How far are you with this? I'm working on some demo for it (off and on), but I'm not sure if it is still relevant... ([intermediate result](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/NWzyzMV))